# What is a sequential injection attack?

Tags: attacks

From the Financial Times 26th October 2015 ["TalkTalk faces mounting calls for compensation"](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/d17f77ee-7b0e-11e5-a1fe-567b37f80b64.html)

> Then, the hackers downloaded customer data using a “sequential injection”. Cyber security experts say this is a well-known technique that is relatively easy to prevent.

What is a sequential injection attack?

Comment: This looks like they mistakenly typed "sequential" instead of SQL (Pronounced sequel). (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: I fear the Financial Times may be also vulnerable to 'cash poisoning' and buffet overflow'

Comment: the writer or editor might have text expander macros that were keyed to "sql"

Comment: It's explained in the media now: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/10/26/talktalk_sequential_attack/. Looks like the official speakers from TalkTalk simply don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: @pr- I think so too. I just wanted to poke light fun and help any confused Financial Times readers .

Comment: So, this question was a joke?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TalkTalk almost certainly meant '[SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)'. However 'sequential injection' has been repeated across the media. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/10/26/talktalk_sequential_attack/

For the curious, this kind of mistake is known as an [*eggcorn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn):

> Eggcorns often involve replacing an unfamiliar, archaic, or obscure word with a more common or modern word (eg. "baited breath" for "bated breath").

Comment: thanks for the eggcorn definition. It still bothers me though, because this isn't archaic, I mean "sequential" is just wrong, right?

Comment: @silentphoenix: "archaic" != "unfamiliar, archaic, or obscure". One of the other cases applies, not the one you singled out. The perspective under consideration is that of overpaid head bean-counters in a state of befuddlement and underpaid failed-novelists in a state of frenzy ;-).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick -- i understand XD however, i am not saying the OP is wrong or anything. I just am saying that it bothers me because sequential has nothing to do with SQL, as sequel stands for Structured Query Language. The OP and you are absolutely correct, it just bothers me because calling it sequential is just wrong. Sorry for the confusion! :D